# Is there a way to make links to search photos on my site automatically with Google Image Search?

Tags: search-engines, google-search

I have a website where members can upload photos.

I am trying to make sure that these are photos that members have the rights to, so when I am concerned, I do a search using Google image search to see where else the photo can be found on the Internet. (http://www.google.com/imghp)

I know there is a Firefox/Chrome extension to allow search by right-clicking an image on a site, but I don't always have a desktop version of Chrome/Firefox available (I often do these checks from a tablet or mobile phone).

So, I would like to find a way to build links on my own site so that I can simply click the link for a photo and then perform the image search on Google.

Is there a way to do this?  I tried looking at the search queries that Google image search produces, but these look different than normal Google search queries when you choose the option to paste the URL in at the start.

Comment: Not as far as I know... Just use a DMCA take down policy and you never need to worry, as long as you act on those requests you're be fine. Thousands of sites allow user generate content and they have no trouble.

Comment: I understand that I can protect myself with a DMCA takedown policy, but I don't have that many users and I would actually like to make the takedowns in advance to improve the quality of my site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [answer from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8325055/how-to-compose-the-url-for-a-reverse-google-image-search#13859357) might be what you're looking for.

Basically, the URL should look like this:

https://www.google.com/searchbyimage?&image_url=`http://path/to/image.jpg`